# How to start a server process from a Java applet?

Tags: java, html, applet, cgi

Right now I'm doing it this way:

Within my applet, I connect to the URL of a CGI script, which starts the server process.

Is there a better way? How would you go about it?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple HTTP call (as I assume you did) is the best way to do this.

There are other network protocols available, but there's the risk they may get blocked for security reasons.

Comment: Indeed, a HTTP call to the aforementioned CGI script. I guess I'll keep it that way then, it's just that sometimes it seems slow (the process finishes faster when ran directly from CMD on the server).
Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all the applet does, then you could do the same thing more simply with a little bit of Javascript embedded in a web page ... or possibly with a simple HTML `<form>` and `<button>` in a webpage.

On the other hand, if the applet is signed and trusted, then you could do pretty much anything that a regular Java application could do.